# How do you get file data out of a file input when there are multiple inputs with the same id on the page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the closest file input as there are multiple with the same ID created by the loop.

I keep getting an undefined error on the file data when posting.

I have tried using "parent", "sibling", "next" and "prev" but seem to get the same error.

This code works on the first element created by the loop.

Thanks

> **HTML**

```
@foreach (var i in Model.Items)
{
    @if (e.Document.DocumentID != null)
    {
        <span><strong>Supporting Document</strong></span><br />
        @e.Document.FileName
    }
    else
    {
       <span><strong>Add a supporting document</strong></span><br /><br />
       <input type="file" id="fileTest" class="fileTest" />
       <button class="btn btn-primary btnSubmit" data-id="@e.RequestID" id="btnSubmit" value="Upload">Upload</button>
     }
 }
```

> **AJAX/JQUERY**

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnSubmit', function () {
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: function () {
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("file", $(this).closest('.fileTest').files[0]);
        return data;
    }(),
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    error: function (response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    },
    success: function (response) {
        BindRequestDetails(response.ret);
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Hi  can you try like this `$(this).prev()[0].files[0]` ?

Comment: Unfortunately i get an "files is not defined" error. Thanks for the help!

Comment: what is `file2` ? your file input has class `fileTest` ?

Comment: should say fileTest, still doesnt work though

Comment: If your id attributes are duplicated, your markup is invalid - IDs must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can surround your inputs around some `div` and then use `$(this).closest("div")` and use `.find("input[type=file]")[0]` to get file .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btnSubmit', function() {

  var data = new FormData();
  //get closest div then find file input get values 
  data.append("file", $(this).closest('div').find("input[type=file]")[0].files[0]);
  console.log($(this).closest('div').find("input[type=file]")[0].files[0])
  //or this way will also work
  console.log($(this).prev()[0].files[0])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- added div around-->
<div>
  <span><strong>Supporting Document</strong></span><br /> @e.Document.FileName
</div>
<!-- added div around-->
<div>
  <span><strong>Add a supporting document</strong></span><br /><br />
  <input type="file" id="fileTest" class="fileTest" />
  <button class="btn btn-primary btnSubmit" data-id="@e.RequestID" id="btnSubmit" value="Upload">Upload</button>
  </div>
  <!-- added div around-->
  <div>
    <span><strong>Add a supporting document</strong></span><br /><br />
    <input type="file" id="fileTest" class="fileTest" />
    <button class="btn btn-primary btnSubmit" data-id="@e.RequestID" id="btnSubmit" value="Upload">Upload</button>
    <div>
```